# Ubuntu 16.04 - degrading wireless performance

Tags: wireless, 16.04, network-manager, ralink, ubuntu-drivers

I have been reading numerous other treads on this issue, and tried a number of things, but still the same problem.

I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 - and that is when the problems started. My wireless connection is perfect - speedtest.net shows download speeds of up to 65 Mbps. A little later (around 10 - 20 minutes - depending on usage) when I realise my Internet connection has deteriorated - same speed check returns speeds as low as 0.5 Mbps. If I just carry on it fails completely at some point as the wifi disconnects, and then continually tries to reconnect with no success.

If I run these commands

```
    sudo modprobe -r rt2800pci
    sudo modprobe -v rt2800pci
```

The connection is perfect once again. For another 10 or 20 minutes, and then the same happens again until I reset it again.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this, or how I can go about making the 'fix' permanent would be highly appreciated.

My 'wireless-info' returns the following

```
    ########## wireless info START ##########

    Report from: 11 Aug 2016 10:36 BST +0100

    Booted last: 11 Aug 2016 00:00 BST +0100

    Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

    ##### release ###########################

    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
    Release:    16.04
    Codename:   xenial

    ##### kernel ############################

    Linux 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

    Parameters: ro

    ##### desktop ###########################

    Ubuntu

    ##### lspci #############################

    07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8P67 and other motherboards [1043:8432]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169

    09:01.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT2800 802.11n PCI [1814:0601]
        Subsystem: Linksys RT2800 802.11n PCI [1737:0067]
        Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci

    ##### lsusb #############################

    Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:0a29 Logitech, Inc. H600 [Wireless Headset]
    Bus 002 Device 003: ID 045e:0040 Microsoft Corp. Wheel Mouse Optical
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

    ##### PCMCIA card info ##################

    ##### rfkill ############################

    2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

    ##### lsmod #############################

    rt2800pci              16384  0
    rt2800mmio             20480  1 rt2800pci
    rt2800lib              94208  2 rt2800pci,rt2800mmio
    rt2x00pci              16384  1 rt2800pci
    rt2x00mmio             16384  2 rt2800pci,rt2800mmio
    rt2x00lib              57344  5 rt2x00pci,rt2800lib,rt2800pci,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio
    mac80211              737280  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00pci,rt2800lib
    cfg80211              565248  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
    eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 rt2800pci
    crc_ccitt              16384  1 rt2800lib
    eeepc_wmi              16384  0
    asus_wmi               28672  1 eeepc_wmi
    sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
    mxm_wmi                16384  0
    video                  40960  2 i915,asus_wmi
    wmi                    20480  2 mxm_wmi,asus_wmi

    ##### interfaces ########################

    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    ##### ifconfig ##########################

    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>  
              UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

    wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>  
              inet addr:192.168.1.67  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:<IP6 'wlan0' [IF2]>/64 Scope:Global
              inet6 addr: fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:e43f:8d69:5553:975e/64 Scope:Global
              inet6 addr: 2a00:23c5:2b00:4e00:<IP6 'wlan0' [IF2]>/64 Scope:Global
              inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'wlan0' [IF2]>/64 Scope:Link
              inet6 addr: 2a00:23c5:2b00:4e00:e43f:8d69:5553:975e/64 Scope:Global
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:91937 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:67241 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:112982621 (112.9 MB)  TX bytes:43095223 (43.0 MB)

    ##### iwconfig ##########################

    lo        no wireless extensions.

    eth0      no wireless extensions.

    wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"BTHub6-5ZWZ"  
              Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.2 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'BTHub6-5ZWZ' [AN4]>   
              Bit Rate=121.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
              Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
              Power Management:on
              Link Quality=42/70  Signal level=-68 dBm  
              Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
              Tx excessive retries:353  Invalid misc:123   Missed beacon:0

    ##### route #############################

    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
    169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
    192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0

    ##### resolv.conf #######################

    nameserver 127.0.1.1
    search home

    ##### network managers ##################

    Installed:

        NetworkManager

    Running:

    root      6704     1  0 09:34 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

    ##### NetworkManager info ###############

    GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
    GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
    GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
    GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Ralink corp.
    GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RT2800 802.11n PCI
    GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rt2800pci
    GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-34-generic
    GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
    GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
    GENERAL.MTU:                            0
    GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
    GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
    GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:08:00.0/0000:09:01.0/net/wlan0
    GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlan0
    GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
    GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
    GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
    GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
    GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
    GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
    GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     BTHub6-5ZWZ
    GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       dc227fab-57af-4967-bab1-6444fad55297
    GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/6
    GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
    CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
    CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     121 Mb/s
    CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
    WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
    WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
    WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
    WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
    WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
    WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
    WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
    WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
    WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
    CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
    CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   dc227fab-57af-4967-bab1-6444fad55297 | BTHub6-5ZWZ
    IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.67/24
    IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.254
    IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
    IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.254
    IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          home
    DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
    DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1470992937
    DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       routers = 192.168.1.254
    DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
    DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.67
    DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       domain_name = home
    DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
    DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
    DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.254
    DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
    DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
    DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_host_name = 1
    DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.254
    IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2a00:23c5:2b00:4e00:e43f:8d69:5553:975e/64
    IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:e43f:8d69:5553:975e/64
    IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         2a00:23c5:2b00:4e00:<IP6 'wlan0' [IF2]>/64
    IP6.ADDRESS[4]:                         fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:<IP6 'wlan0' [IF2]>/64
    IP6.ADDRESS[5]:                         fe80::<IP6 'wlan0' [IF2]>/64
    IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::924d:4aff:fe0f:1d45
    IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 2a00:23c5:2b00:4e00::/64, nh = fe80::924d:4aff:fe0f:1d45, mt = 600
    IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fdaa:bbcc:ddee::/64, nh = fe80::924d:4aff:fe0f:1d45, mt = 600
    DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        requested_dhcp6_domain_search = 1
    DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_domain_search = home.
    DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        requested_dhcp6_client_id = 1
    DHCP6.OPTION[4]:                        requested_dhcp6_name_servers = 1
    DHCP6.OPTION[5]:                        dhcp6_server_id = 0:1:0:1:18:74:e3:b4:90:4d:4a:f:1d:45
    DHCP6.OPTION[6]:                        dhcp6_client_id = 0:4:29:57:28:7e:a5:6:2d:33:9c:f1:82:68:d:4:46:d3

    GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
    GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
    GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
    GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (P8P67 and other motherboards)
    GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
    GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
    GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12
    GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>
    GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
    GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
    GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
    GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6/0000:07:00.0/net/eth0
    GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
    GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
    GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
    GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
    GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
    GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
    GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
    GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
    GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
    GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
    GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
    CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
    CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
    CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
    WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
    CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

    SSID                    BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY          ACTIVE  * 
    BTHub6-5ZWZ             <MAC 'BTHub6-5ZWZ' [AN1]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  69      ▂▄▆_  WPA2              no        
    BTWifi-with-FON         <MAC 'BTWifi-with-FON' [AN2]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  --                no        
    BTHub5-FXPN             <MAC 'BTHub5-FXPN' [AN3]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA2              no        
    BTHub6-5ZWZ             <MAC 'BTHub6-5ZWZ' [AN4]>  Infra  40    5200 MHz  54 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA2              yes     * 
    BTWifi-X                <MAC 'BTWifi-X' [AN5]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X  no        
    TALKTALK-D149D4         <MAC 'TALKTALK-D149D4' [AN6]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2         no        
    BTWifi-with-FON         <MAC 'BTWifi-with-FON' [AN7]>  Infra  44    5220 MHz  54 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  --                no        
    BTHub5-FXPN             <MAC 'BTHub5-FXPN' [AN8]>  Infra  44    5220 MHz  54 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA2              no        
    BTWifi-X                <MAC 'BTWifi-X' [AN9]>  Infra  44    5220 MHz  54 Mbit/s  44      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X  no        
    DIRECT-BB-Android_8d05  <MAC 'DIRECT-BB-Android_8d05' [AN10]>  Infra  44    5220 MHz  54 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA2              no        

    ##### NetworkManager.state ##############

    [main]
    NetworkingEnabled=true
    WirelessEnabled=true
    WWANEnabled=true
    WimaxEnabled=true

    ##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

    [main]
    plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
    dns=dnsmasq

    [ifupdown]
    managed=false

    ##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

    [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BTHub6-5ZWZ]] (600 root)
    [connection] id=BTHub6-5ZWZ | type=802-11-wireless
    [802-11-wireless] ssid=BTHub6-5ZWZ | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
    [ipv4] method=auto
    [ipv6] method=auto

    ##### iw reg get ########################

    Region: Europe/London (based on set time zone)

    country GB: DFS-ETSI
        (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
        (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
        (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS
        (5490 - 5710 @ 160), (N/A, 27), (0 ms), DFS
        (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

    ##### iwlist channels ###################

    lo        no frequency information.

    eth0      no frequency information.

    wlan0     32 channels in total; available frequencies :
              Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
              Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
              Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
              Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
              Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
              Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
              Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
              Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
              Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
              Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
              Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
              Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
              Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
              Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
              Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
              Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
              Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
              Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
              Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
              Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
              Channel 54 : 5.27 GHz
              Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
              Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
              Channel 62 : 5.31 GHz
              Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
              Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
              Channel 102 : 5.51 GHz
              Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
              Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
              Channel 110 : 5.55 GHz
              Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
              Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
              Current Frequency:5.2 GHz (Channel 40)

    ##### iwlist scan #######################

    lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

    wlan0     Failed to read scan data : Resource temporarily unavailable

    eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

    ##### module infos ######################

    [rt2800pci]
    filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800pci.ko
    license:        GPL
    firmware:       rt2860.bin
    description:    Ralink RT2800 PCI & PCMCIA Wireless LAN driver.
    version:        2.3.0
    author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
    srcversion:     26CCED9E0CE5EFBFA9B8882
    depends:        rt2x00lib,rt2800lib,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio,rt2x00pci,eeprom_93cx6
    intree:         Y
    vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
    parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)

    [rt2800mmio]
    filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800mmio.ko
    license:        GPL
    description:    rt2800 MMIO library
    version:        2.3.0
    author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
    srcversion:     01C1A7641505065E52E0388
    depends:        rt2800lib,rt2x00lib,rt2x00mmio
    intree:         Y
    vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

    [rt2800lib]
    filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800lib.ko
    license:        GPL
    description:    Ralink RT2800 library
    version:        2.3.0
    author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com, Bartlomiej Zolnierkiewicz
    srcversion:     BB9F48B63A82C3FD3E73BAF
    depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211,crc-ccitt
    intree:         Y
    vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

    [rt2x00pci]
    filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00pci.ko
    license:        GPL
    description:    rt2x00 pci library
    version:        2.3.0
    author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
    srcversion:     543B84557258F153AC267F0
    depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211
    intree:         Y
    vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

    [rt2x00mmio]
    filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00mmio.ko
    license:        GPL
    description:    rt2x00 mmio library
    version:        2.3.0
    author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
    srcversion:     ADBE279820CFD0A1081C682
    depends:        rt2x00lib
    intree:         Y
    vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

    [rt2x00lib]
    filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00lib.ko
    license:        GPL
    description:    rt2x00 library
    version:        2.3.0
    author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
    srcversion:     72E39180D883A5541F66494
    depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
    intree:         Y
    vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

    [mac80211]
    filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
    license:        GPL
    description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
    srcversion:     2FFAEED0245CA1D97FE1E44
    depends:        cfg80211
    intree:         Y
    vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
    parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
    parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
    parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
    parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
    parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
    parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

    [cfg80211]
    filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
    description:    wireless configuration support
    license:        GPL
    author:         Johannes Berg
    srcversion:     25A45701AAA64DAC1E47D9D
    depends:        
    intree:         Y
    vermagic:       4.4.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
    parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
    parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

    ##### module parameters #################

    [rt2800pci]
    nohwcrypt: Y

    [mac80211]
    beacon_loss_count: 7
    ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
    max_nullfunc_tries: 2
    max_probe_tries: 5
    minstrel_vht_only: Y
    probe_wait_ms: 500

    [cfg80211]
    cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
    ieee80211_regdom: 00

    ##### /etc/modules ######################

    lp

    coretemp
    nct6775

    coretemp
    nct6775

    ##### modprobe options ##################

    [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
    blacklist ath_pci

    [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
    blacklist evbug
    blacklist usbmouse
    blacklist usbkbd
    blacklist eepro100
    blacklist de4x5
    blacklist eth1394
    blacklist snd_intel8x0m
    blacklist snd_aw2
    blacklist i2c_i801
    blacklist prism54
    blacklist bcm43xx
    blacklist garmin_gps
    blacklist asus_acpi
    blacklist snd_pcsp
    blacklist pcspkr
    blacklist amd76x_edac

    [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
    alias net-pf-3 off
    alias net-pf-6 off
    alias net-pf-9 off
    alias net-pf-11 off
    alias net-pf-12 off
    alias net-pf-19 off
    alias net-pf-21 off
    alias net-pf-36 off

    [/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
    remove iwlwifi \
    (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
    && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
    options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8

    [/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
    softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

    [/etc/modprobe.d/rt2800pci.conf]
    options rt2800pci nohwcrypt=1

    [/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf]
    options rtl8723be fwlps=N

    ##### rc.local ##########################

    exit 0

    ##### pm-utils ##########################

    [/etc/pm/config.d/config] (644 root)
    SUSPEND_MODULES="RTL8111/8168/8411"

    ##### udev rules ########################

    [/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
    # PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
    SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
    # PCI device 0x1814:0x0601 (rt2800pci)
    SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

    ##### dmesg #############################

    [ 6171.962712] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush (repeated 59 times)
    [ 6199.904495] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_rxdone_read_signal: Warning - Frame received with unrecognized signal, mode=0x0000, signal=0x0000, type=4 (repeated 8 times)
    [ 6200.260461] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush (repeated 33 times)

    ########## wireless info END ############
```

Thanks

... I want to bump this to the top again

Comment: Since posting this - I have tried the following
 - Loading earlier kernel ( 4.4.31)
 - Disabled IPV6
 - Tried to load backports, but the 'make' fails with errors

Is there anyone that has any ide what else I could try ?

Comment: I have now also tried loading even earlier kernel - still same problem.

Comment: Does anyone else have similar issues ? Nobody seems to have solved the issues on other Questions that were similar, but dating back to 2011 ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally after more than a week of frustration - I think I have found a solution to this issue - of there is anyone else out there that wants to pull their hair out, don't do it.

It seems that solving this specific problem - which goes hand-in-hand with the pesky

```
rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
```

errors in /var/log/syslog requires the following action

Run the following command

```
 iwconfig
```

and get the MAC address of the Access Point. I entered this into the BSSID field on the Network setup screen on the wifi tab

[IMAGE showing relevant fields on Ubuntu 16.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyNH6.png)

Hope this helps someone else!!

=========================================================================

An hour later I noticed the internet speed dropping down to 1 - 3 Mbps again ... and noticed from the /var/log/syslog that it happened the same time as an IRQ16 problem.

So I followed the recommendations to add "irqpoll" to the boot options.

To add that in Ubuntu 16.04 - one needs to 
Edit the file **/etc/default/grub**
Edit / Add a line to include the following

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="irqpoll"
```

If you already have values in there  - just add it on the end like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash irqpoll"
```

To update the grub cfg - run the following

```
sudo update-grub
```

You can check if the irqpoll has been added to your cfg file by doing

```
cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep irqpoll
```

You should be able to spot a few entries.

After a REBOOT - my machine was perfect - 24 hours on - still the case !