# Ubuntu 16.04 Weak WiFi Signal after dual boot Ralink Rt3290

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, ralink

I am new to Ubuntu. For the last 3 complete days I have been looking for a solution to this problem with no luck. I have read almost all the similar question posted on Ask Ubuntu but there is no solution. Few people mark the question as Duplicate. Instead of marking it as duplicate and redirecting to other link can anyone please answer the question here.

**Weak WiFi signal,** have to sit very close to the router to work(3-4 feet).
I have **dual booted window** and installed **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**


Network controller: **Ralink corp. RT3290** Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe


In this Ask Ubuntu [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into/61547#61547), it was written to add the output of these commands:

1. sudo lshw -class network
2. lsusb
3. lspci
4. dmesg
5. dmesg | grep -i firmware

   So i am adding them here.

```
1.
sachin@sachin-hp:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for sachin: 
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 54:35:30:61:53:35
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.10.0-32-generic firmware=0.37 ip=192.168.0.106 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:b5510000-b551ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 08
       serial: a0:1d:48:e2:c8:41
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b5404000-b5404fff memory:b5400000-b5403fff
```

```
2.
sachin@sachin-hp:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b40e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Truevision HD camera
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
3.
sachin@sachin-hp:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
08:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
08:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 08)
0a:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
```

4. dmesg
   output of this command was very long so i had to uploaded it [here on Google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzxaFQDLiAj8MnQyUEpKV1dSWEE)

```
5.
sachin@sachin-hp:~$ dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.185726] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.517466] [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (0)
[    1.734150] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[   26.991234] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt3290.bin'
[   26.999832] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.37
```

This is the first time i am posting a question so forgive me if i make any mistake.
Please let me know if any other information is need to solve this problem. Help please!!!

Comment: Welcome to AU. Can you check if power management is on or off with the `iwconfig` command. Also, use http://pastebin.com instead of google drive for outputs. Last but not least, is that bold really necessary? We can read plain text.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Power management is ON.
I thought of highlighting the main points of my question. There are many similar question on Ask Ubuntu. I don't really know what pastebin is but i will give it a try in future posts.

Comment: Try to temporarily turn it off with `sudo iwconfig wlo1 power off`to check if things get better. Also, you might want to use pastebin.com now, and post there your dmesg. I can't access google drive.

Comment: No turning off power management didn't help. Also here is the link to command output in pastebin https://pastebin.com/GtjTZmnA

Comment: Thanks, there are quite a few of these: `ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush`, and I've found [similar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/810924/ubuntu-16-04-degrading-wireless-performance) [reports](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815891/16-04-wifi-ethernet-issues-after-updating-from-14-04), also with the `rt2800pci` driver. There is no clear solution or workaround. You might want to try changing the router's wireless mode to 11g only, or some other suggestions.

Comment: I tried changing my Wi-Fi  adapter to 802.11n Wireless LAN card, but that didn't solve the problem. I am using ethernet cable now.  Also on this [webpage](https://connectwww.com/how-to-solve-realtek-rtl8723be-weak-wifi-signal-problem-in-ubuntu/4625/) they have solved the problem of weak wifi for rtl8723be.